# $_POST values not pulling through with jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to post my data into my database (entered via controlpanel.php, processed with name.php) BUT my $_POST values don't pull through to name.php when I submit the data with jquery. I'm new to jquery and I'm trying to figure out why this is happening?

test_process.js

```
$('#insert_submit').on('click', function(event) {
alert("Hello");
event.preventDefault();
var insert_name = $('#insert_template_name').val();
$.post('ajax/name.php', {name: insert_name}, function(data) {
    $('#insert_data').text(data);
    });      
});
```

ajax/name.php

```
<?php
include('C:\xampp\htdocs\email1\class\db.php');
require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\email1\config\db.php');
require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\email1\class\Login.php');

    $login = new Login();
    $user = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $db = new Database();
    $db->connect();

    //test
    echo $_POST['insert_template'];
    echo '<br/>' . $_POST['insert_template_name'];

    //insert    
     if (isset($_POST['insert_template'])) {
     $template_name = $db->escape($_POST['insert_template_name']);
    $template_description = $db->escape($_POST['insert_template']);
    $db->insert('templates', array('template_name' => $template_name, 'template_description' => $template_description, 'userID' => $user)); 

    echo "Inserted successfully";
     }
```

Controlpanel.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h2><u>Insert</u></h2>
<form action="ajax/name.php" name="insert_template_form" id="insert_template_form method="post">
<textarea rows="10" cols="25" name="insert_template" id="insert_template"></textarea>  <br/>
 Name your template: <input type="text" name="insert_template_name" id="insert_template_name"/><br/>
 <input type="submit" name="insert_submit" value="submit" id="insert_submit"/></form>
 <div id="insert_data"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="test_process.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have forgotten to close the `id` attribute of the `form` tag: `id="insert_template_form method="post"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only passing one parameter to your PHP code:

```
$.post('ajax/name.php', {name: insert_name}, function(data) {
                         ^^^^---here
```

and nowhere in your PHP code do you have `$_POST['name']`. So therefore your insert query is using an undefined variable.

Comment: This is correct, OP should use `echo $_POST['name'];` to test.

Comment: Yep, that's it! How would I have more than one name value i.e {name: insert_name, name2: insert_template}?

Comment: just because it's ajax doesn't mean it's doing anything magical. ajax is a plain-jane HTTP request that just happens to be done in the "background" of a page. Nothing you do in JS can change that fact. if you're sending two parameters in the `{...}` data block in the .ajax() call, you're going to get two equivalent parameters in on the server in $_GET/$_POST, as appropriate.